# azure v2.8 cloud service diagnostics

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-diagnostics

I've had a site running on a azure 2.4 cloud service for some time without any problems. This site is using diagnostics to log errors and user inputs to a wad_logs_table in a storage account. After upgrading to 2.8 this doesn't work anymore.

Ive tried to enable diagnostics after upgrade and configure the "new" config diagnostics.wadcfgx file with storage account info, but I don't think it is working. As I understand it will not be using the wad_logs_table anymore? What do I need to change? Where can I access the logs?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share diagnostics configuration file? I went through the same process (upgraded from 2.4 to 2.6) and I can say it works fine. Your trace logs data should show up in WadLogsTable table.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks. I've must have misunderstood something about where it would store the data. I couldn't get it to work in the emulator, but after setting the right trace level and publish to azure it works and it shows up in the WadLogsTable.

Comment: @freddy Did you get it working ?